# Related rates problem involving a rectangle on a coordinate plane

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

I have been stuck on this problem for a while and I need help!

> A rectangle exists in the coordinate plane so that one of its sides is a segment on the $y$-axis and the adjacent side is a segment on the $x$-axis. The upper-right corner of the rectangle lies on the curve $x^3-2xy^2+y^3+1=0$, and is moving (causing the sides of the rectangle to change their lengths). How fast is the area of the rectangle changing at the instant the corner passes through the point $(2,3)$ if the corner is moving so that $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$ unit per second?
>
> *Hint: Draw a picture. Even if you don't know what the curve looks like, draw a generic curve so you can label your rectangle!*
>
> *Hint: You are looking for the rate of change of the area, but you should represent it with an expression of given variables instead of calling it $A$*
>
> *Hint: This is going to involve implicit differentiation*
>
> *Hint: Like some types of shadow problems, you'll have to solve for one rate before you can find the rate you want*

Comment: I typed up the question for you. However, as is, the question will be closed, since you haven't shown any efforts or context of your own. What have you tried?

Comment: From now on, please type your questions instead of linking photos.

Comment: The problem is that I actually have no idea where to start. I have not done this type of problem in my class and just confused about where to start.

Comment: There are $4$ hints...

Comment: I will attempt this question again and see what I can do.

Comment: ok so, I used implicit differentiation on the given equation and I plugged in 2 for x and 3 for y. Using the given value of dx/dt I found dy/dt to be 2/5. From there I put A=xy for the area of the rectangle. I found dA/dt expression and plugged in the values to get 19/5 units/sec. Can anyone confirm that I did this right?

Comment: Can you edit that into the question? With MathJax?

Comment: ok so, I used implicit differentiation on the given equation $x^3 - 2xy^2 +y^3 +1 =0$ and I plugged in 2 for x and 3 for y. Using the given value of $dx$/$dt$ I found $dy/dt$ to be $2/5$. From there I used the equation $A=xy$ in order to represent the area of the rectangle. I found $dA/dt$ to be $(x)($dx/dt$)$ + $(y)($dy/dt$)$  and I plugged in the values to get $19/5$ units/sec. Can anyone confirm that I did this right?

Comment: I'm still new to using MathJax, but I hope this helps